# ORM framework compare to direct query in database

Tags: c#, database, orm

I want to write a program for warehousing.

Can anyone guide me in using a framework for the database layer?

I have used entity framework before but did not enjoy it because it throws many unknown errors.

Does anyone suggest NHibernate or any other framework, or do you think if I use straight queries or store procedures, it will be more reliable and better?

Comment: Learn using an ORM first. "lot of unknon errors" are not an Entity Fraemwork problem, hey are aproblem of the person in front of the computer. ORMs awork wonderfull - though EF is a disputable mediocre ont. But unless you know what you do... an ORM wont magically fix thigs. And ORM's are not used FOR a DAL - they contain one. They are abusiness layer tool - the runtime for persistent objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think ORM is the best choice for this sort of problem.

The 'O' in ORM stands for 'object'.  You don't want to have to create an object model just to move data into a warehouse.

ORM is more for developer convenience: to allow object-oriented programmers to forget the difference between instance-based objects on the middle tier and set-based relations on the database side.  The SQL is generated by the ORM tool.  It might not be what you'd want to move data.

I think the three letters you really need to dive into are ETL: Extract-Transfer-Load.  That's the more typical approach used to move data from a transactional data store into a data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework throws errors that are normally from your database such as constraints etc. However, you can also do direct SQL and stored procedure calls using Entity Framework too.

You should also correct your title to ORM not OMR?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an over-belief in ORM-frameworks. They have issues like slow performance and what not. Use Linq-to-sql would be a suggestion with more advanced queries done as stored procedures. It's pretty straight forward and stable.
Or use SubSonic. In fact, there's nothing wrong with doing a lot of stored procedures if you feel like it. There are no magic bullets - every solution has it's pros and cons.